# Symfony2 classless form with choices: retrieving submitted data

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am having a problem using symfony2 and a classless form with a choice field.

The setup is very, very simple:

```
$data=array();
$choices=array(1 => 'A thing', 2 => 'This other thing', 100 => 'That other thing');

$fb=$this->createFormBuilder($data);
$fb->add('mythings', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => $choices,
        'data' => $data,
        'required' => false,
        'expanded' => true, 
        'multiple' => true,
        'mapped' => false))->
    add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Save'));
$form=$fb->getForm();
```

And then...

```
$request=$this->getRequest();
$form->handleRequest($request);
if($form->isValid())
{
    //Go nuts.
}
```

It is in the "go nuts" part where I am stuck. I actually need to access the selected choices by their original index as given in the $choices array... And I haven't been able to. This is the closest I got:

```
$submitted_data=$form->get('mythings'); 
foreach($submitted_data as $key => $value) 
{   
echo $key.' -> '.$value->getData().'<br />'; 
}
```

Which assuming we mark the first and last choices, yields:

```
0 -> 1
1 ->  
2 -> 1
```

It is absolutely necessary that this be a classless form. How do I access the original index (in our case, 1, 2 or 100) of the choices?.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$form->get('mythings')->getData()
```

will give you data that you need.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried something like that and just got "1" or null depending on the checkbox being checked or not. You can see it in the original post, only there's a foreach there. I am fairly new to symfony so everything is still a bit sketchy. Thanks anyway.

Comment: it gives an array in following format:  array(0 => 1, 2=>100); dump it to get more details.

Comment: Okay, seems like I missed the second getData call... I tried $form->get->('mythings') and then tried to iterate it and call get->Data() on each item. Your way actually made it work. Accepted answer. Thanks a lot :).

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue with field mapping. the data you're passing into the form needs to be applied to the field you're adding ('mythings') so you have to wrap $data in an array as a value to the key 'mythings'.

For example:

```
$data=array();
$choices=array(1 => 'A thing', 2 => 'This other thing', 100 => 'That other thing');

$fb=$this->createFormBuilder(array('mythings' => $data));
$fb->add('mythings', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => $choices,
    'required' => false,
    'expanded' => true, 
    'multiple' => true))
   ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Save'));

$form=$fb->getForm();
```

Comment: Hmmm... Did not do it. Office hours are done. Will take a good look tomorrow. Still, thanks a lot.

Comment: For reference: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#using-a-form-without-a-class

Answer (score 1):

you could try naming the array keys to preserve the actual index

```
$data=array();
$choices=array('1' => 'A thing', '2' => 'This other thing', '100' => 'That other thing');

$fb=$this->createFormBuilder($data);
$fb->add('mythings', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => $choices,
        'data' => $data,
        'required' => false,
        'expanded' => true, 
        'multiple' => true,
        'mapped' => false))->
    add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Save'));
$form=$fb->getForm();
```

Comment: That's strange... Normally this should do the job as you can see [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#example-usage)

Comment: Yeah, I think I am doing a bad setup in the real production code. Based on the answer by SA Alex I would think that the data array passed to the classless Form dictates the "structure" of the data. The real production code is a bit different. Will look into it tomorrow. Thanks a lot.